# Invoking Func passed as a parameter to a mock using Moq and C#

Tags: c#, .net, moq, capture, xunit

I have a mocked method that looks like this:

```
class NotMineClass {
  T Execute(Func operation) 
  {
    // do something
    return operation();
  }
}
```

In my code, I do such as:

```
public MyType MyMethod()
{
  MyType object = new MyType();
  bool success = notMineClassInstance.Execute(() =>
  {
    // some things
    retVal = injectedObject1.method();
    object.attribute = injectedObject2.method();
    // some other things
    return retVal;
  }
  if (success) 
  {
    object.otherAttribute = someValue;
  }
  return object;
}
```

My case is, I am testing MyMethod with Moq and I want to verify the Func behaviour is as expected. I have some injected objects in its body, that are mocks, and should be verified; it also starts building my return value, so I can't do any assertion unless I invoke the function passed as parameter.

In Java and jUnit + EasyMock , I would capture the parameter passed, like this:

```
public void testMyMethod() {
  // ...
  Capture < Function < void, Boolean > > functionCapture = Captures.last();
  expect(notMineClassInstance.execute(EasyMock.capture(functionCapture)));
  // Expectations for the body of the function

  replay();

  functionCapture.getValue().apply(null);
}
```

How do I do the same using C# + Moq?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can capture invocation argument when provide `Returns` for method:

```
Mock<NotMineClassInstance> mock = new Mock<NotMineClassInstance>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Execute<bool>(It.IsAny<Func<bool>>()))
    .Returns((Func<bool> captured) => { captured(); return true; });
```

Here is complete test for your code:

```
[Test]
public void TestingSomething()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<NotMineClassInstance> mockNotMine = new Mock<NotMineClassInstance>();
    mockDep.Setup(x => x.Execute<bool>(It.IsAny<Func<bool>>())).Returns((Func<bool> func) => func());

    Mock<Injected1> mockInjected1 = new Mock<Injected1>();
    mockInjected1.Setup(i => i.Method()).Returns(true);

    Mock<Injected2> mockInjected2 = new Mock<Injected2>();
    mockInjected2.Setup(i => i.Method()).Returns("xxx");

    YourClass yourObject = new YourClass(mockDep.Object, mockInjected1.Object, mockInjected2.Object);

    // Act
    MyType my = yourObject.MyMethod();    

    // Assert
    mockNotMine.Verify(d => d.Execute<bool>(It.IsAny<Func<bool>>()));
    mockInjected1.Verify(i => i.Method());
    mockInjected2.Verify(i => i.Method());

    Assert.That(my.Attribute, Is.EqualTo("xxx"));
    Assert.That(my.OtherAttribute, Is.EqualTo(someValue));            
}
```

Also you need test for case when mockInjected1.Method returns false.

Comment: Looks great, but when I do this, I get the following error: *Test' failed: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Test.<Test>b__0(Func`1 captured)*

Comment: @LuísGuilherme see complete test sample

Comment: It worked since the beginning. I was getting a Null Reference inside the Func call :)

Comment: I want to mention `ReturnsAsync` method, too. Year, everything is tricky to configure in this way but possible. It works! Just look to definitions of used methods and objects. Tnks